# How to use flatpickr rangePlugin in Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, flatpickr

I want to use flatpickr with rangePlugin in my Angular project, but I cannot instantiate the rangePlugin after importing the plugin in TypeScript.

**TypeScript error:**
`Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.ts(2350)`

The way I import the plugin is:

```
import rangePlugin from 'flatpickr/dist/plugins/rangePlugin';
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';
```

I try to use the plugin this way:

```
const range = new rangePlugin({ input: '#datepicker2' }));
```

which produces the error mentioned above.

**How can I import the rangePlugin correctly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// First do the imports
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';
import rangePlugin from 'flatpickr/dist/plugins/rangePlugin';

// Then you can use the flatpickr anyway you want inside ngOnInit, as plain javascript
ngOnInit(): void {
    flatpickr("#enterYourIdHere", {
        plugins: [
            rangePlugin({
                //Enter your options here
            })
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: How Can I show this range picklist on the button click

Answer (score 1):

Te error speaks for itself. Remove the 'new' from the function.

```
plugins: [rangePlugin({ input: myInput })]
```

You also need to declare the element you're going to pass to the rangePlugin function.

```
const myInput = document.getElementById('datepicker2') as HTMLInputElement;
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
declare const flatpickr: any;
```

instead of

```
 import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';
```

or

look for that.

https://flatpickr.js.org/getting-started/#usage

Comment: That's not the answer to the question above.